# How to make a bar plot with three variables on R base?

Tags: r, database, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

my dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bNfst2aWN6ByJ4fLHpMWCZtNcpJg4Dss/view), and my code is this:

```
ggplot(data_summary, aes(x = factor(Temp), y = mean, fill = Glass)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5, colour = "gray25")  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.25,
                show.legend = FALSE, colour = "gray25") +
  labs(x="Temperature (˚C)", y="Light Output") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.75)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Tukey), position = position_dodge(0.90), size = 3, 
            vjust=-0.8, hjust=-0.5, colour = "gray25") +
  ylim(0, 1500) +
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zI4l.png)

my question is: how to make this chart with R base?

Comment: Why the impetus to make it in base graphics? Regardless ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/37931327/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23142684/3358272 should help you.

Comment: @r2evans It's for a course on introduction to R. Oh, and THANK YOU!